# What years does "The Peripheral" take place in?

Tags: william-gibson, the-peripheral

I recently read *The Peripheral* by William Gibson, and I had fun trying to keep track of when it could have taken place (similarly to *Neuromancer*, it's vague). I have some guesses, but does anyone have the definite years it takes place (possibly something I missed in the book, or possible to work out)? If not, what are the possible year-ranges the book could take place in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**2096 - 2138(ish)**

In the book, there is a passing reference to the protagonist's receiving a souvenir from [Clanton's bicentennial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clanton,_Alabama) when she was 8 years old.

> She found herself looking at the plastic tray propped on the
>   mantelpiece, the one with the aerial-view cartoon map from Clanton’s
>   bicentennial year. **Her mother had driven the three of them over for
>   the celebrations, when she was eight.** She remembered it, but it seemed
>   like somebody else’s life.

Assuming she's in her 30's, this places the lower bound in the late 2090s.

---

> There was the mantelpiece, the one with the commemorative plastic tray whose duplicate he’d seen in Clovis Fearing’s shop in Portobello Road, a pale oblong propped against the wall. He rolled forward, the camera bobbing annoyingly, **until he could make out “Clanton Bicentennial,” and the dates. And seventy-some years on from the year of celebration,** he sat at Lev’s grandfather’s desk in the Gobiwagen

This places the upper bound in the 2130s.

Comment: This answer does, of course rely on the assumption that Gibson used the founding of the **real** Clanton, Alabama as his source date.

Comment: ^ I was thinking the same thing. Originally I thought the 2090s would be the upper bound, since (I believe) Netherton made reference once to the 1900s as the century before Flynne's, which was the century before his, putting Flynne in the 2000s and Netherton's the 2100s.

Answer (score 6):

**2132** in the parent timeline (the "big stub," Wilf's timeline).

Now that *Agency* is out, the dates are much clearer.  *Agency* takes place in **2136**<sup>1</sup> and, according to Conner Penske, 4 years have passed<sup>2</sup> since the events of *The Peripheral*.  Hence *The Peripheral* happens in 2132 in Wilf's timeline.

(Note that it's established several times that time passes at the same rate in the "big stub" as all the other stubs.  Examples: "a fixed ratio of duration with their continuum: one to one."<sup>3</sup> and "a one-to-one temporal ratio"<sup>4</sup>)

**2061** in Flynne's timeline ("the county").

Wilf refers to Flynne's timeline as "seventy-some years earlier"<sup>5</sup> and "seventy-some years before"<sup>6</sup> and when Flynne relates her briefing by Wilf and Ash to Burton he asks "Just over seventy years?"<sup>7</sup>  But we can be more accurate than that.  In *Agency*, Ash says Conner is staying in Washington with Leon: "This is Leon's first year in office, so it's helpful for him to have someone from home."<sup>8</sup>   That places the date in the year following a U.S. election year.  U.S. election years around 70 years previous to 2132 are 2052, 2056, 2060, 2064; a year after those election years are 2053, 2057, 2061 and 2065, differences of 79, 75, 71 and 67 years.  Only 1 of those numbers, 71, would be "just over seventy."

However, there are a few inconsistencies in the story, primarily the ages of Lowbeer and Clovis Fearing.  In *The Peripheral* when we meet Clovis and Griff in Flynne's stub, they are respectively "a little older"<sup>9</sup> than and "not quite as old"<sup>10</sup> as she.  But in *Agency* they are both "a hundred and twenty-something,"<sup>11</sup> which would make Flynne 50-plus, given a 71-year difference between the timelines, which she obviously is not.  (Note that this is the only inconsistency with their ages; in *Agency* Lowbeer is said to be "a child" in 2017,<sup>11</sup> which fits with an age of 120-something in 2136.)

There is also some confusion about the timing of the jackpot.  Wilf regularly refers to Flynne's timeline as "pre-jackpot" or "the far side of the jackpot"<sup>6</sup> but there are also references to the jackpot starting earlier than 2061: "midcentury, just as the jackpot really got going"<sup>12</sup> and elsewhere being underway by the 2040s.

The date of the Clanton Bicentennial (presumably 2068, since there is only 1 Clanton listed in my gazetteer) is also problematic; if Flynne were 8 at that time,<sup>13</sup> she would be 27 (her most probable age<sup>14</sup>) around 2088, only 44 years distant from Wilf's time.  This date can't be right, since that would be deep into the jackpot and the devastation would have had a major and obvious effect on Flynne's timeline by then.  (Even the fact that Wilf thinks it's "seventy-some years on from the year of celebration"<sup>15</sup> is either an error on his part or the editor's, since it directly contradicts the 70-year span given by multiple characters.  But it works if it should have been "ninety-some.")

<sup>1</sup> *Agency* ch. 53 "Over London"
<sup>2</sup> *Agency* ch. 61 "Continental Breakfast"
<sup>3</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 24 "Anathema"
<sup>4</sup> *Agency* ch. 63 "Users"
<sup>5</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 20 "Polt"
<sup>6</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 12 "Archaism"
<sup>7</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 45 "Up There"
<sup>8</sup> *Agency* ch. 63 "Users"
<sup>9</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 81 "Alamo"
<sup>10</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 87 "The Antidote for Party Time"
<sup>11</sup> *Agency* ch. 73 "Singularity"
<sup>12</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 12 "Thylacine"
<sup>13</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 59 "Adventure Capitalists"
<sup>14</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 13 "Easy Ice"
<sup>15</sup> *The Peripheral* ch. 98 "Bicentennial"